# Cascade in Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, cascade

I'm a newbie in Laravel and I have a question.

I want to Eloquent (ORM) behaves like JPA (Java) managing collections using cascade.

If I have a list with "N" elements and passing it to the ORM, then the ORM inserts and deletes the changes automatically. (In hasMany relationships)

Is that possible?

Thanks

Regards.

Nicolás

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ORM inserts automatically?

Comment: In java... Your Object has a HasMany (OneToMany) relationship and you can modify the collection, after that, when you persist the object, the ORM persists the new objects in the collection or deletes the objects what are not present in collection anymore. Excuse me but I am not a English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> You may specify the desired action for the "on delete" and "on update" properties of the constraint:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints